# INSERT INTO STATEMENT not working in my for-each loop

Tags: java, sql, for-loop, jdbc

I have a code like this,

```
Let m = 7;

for(int i=0, i<m, i++){
 con.setAutoCommit(false)
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Numbers VALUES (i, "This is   sparta")");
 ps.executeUpdate();
 con.commit();
 con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

Now the problem is, my database table is looking like this...

```
Number       Name
________________________________
1234567      This is sparta
```

instead of...

```
Number        Name
_________________________________
1         This is sparta

2         This is sparta

3         This is sparta

4         This is sparta

5         This is sparta

6         This is sparta

7         This is sparta
```

Where have I gone horribly wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please post real code, what you have there can't compile.

Comment: Two comments. 1) Use a `PreparedStatement` as intended, create the statement with `INSERT INTO Numbers VALUES (?,?)` then bind the values. 2) This query horribly wrong, post the one that doesn't throw a massive error.

Comment: If you don't want to post real code then make sure that this one will compile and reproduce your problem in way you describe it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a prepared statement even if you make it work.You should use value placeholder 
to take full advantages of PreparedStatement

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);

final String value = "This is Xerxes";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Numbers VALUES (?,?)");
for (int i=0, i<m, i++){

    ps.setInt(1,i);
    ps.setString(2,value);
    ps.executeUpdate(); 
}
ps.close();

con.commit();
```

You should make it a single commit after all insert statement has completed

Comment: Hi, I keep getting this error 'Data truncation: Out of range value for column, 'Number'. Its because it is not creating 7 records and instead creating one record with values 1-7. How do I fix this?

Comment: Delete the old content first; it should work. Maybe you have an autoincrement field for the first number field with restricted number of digits. Then it is best to have simply `number INT AUTOINCR` without restriction to 1 digit, or drop the AUTOINCR.

Comment: @Joop thanks for declaring the prepared statement outside the loop and also closing it :)

Comment: @Joop Sorry where should I put the try and catch block?

Comment: @user3448572 He never said anything about handling the exception.JDBC exceptions should be prevented from coming in the first place rather than handling it in code itself

Comment: As of Java 7 one could do `try (PreparedStatement ps = con.pre...) { for { } } catch (SQLException e) { ... }` (without close). But if you would like to show what individual values caused the error, the content of the for loop has to receive try-catch too.

Comment: @JoopEggen is 100% right.If your main exception is getting masked because of some reason,ry with resources is the perfect thing.It closes all the resources without masking the main exception .

Comment: @JoopEggen Yo ushould post this as an answer.Seriously

Comment: @JoopEggen I am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException, for some unknown reason. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar thanks for the suggestion, but let's consider it a common solution, and post-edit your answer. I have got enough points.

Comment: A NumberFormatException can easily happen. A stacktrace helps to locate the error. It could be an empty string, or any thing like a spurious space or missing period in a parseDouble. If the value comes from the database use getInt instead of `parseInt(getString())`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I tried parseInt still not luck :(. I want to insert the values into the database, and I was using String.format to convert the numbers so that it looked like 001, 002, 003... How should I declare it in my database scheme? SMALLINT(3) or INT(3)

Comment: Before Java 7 preceding numbers made it octal numbers where 008 would go wrong. If you were using Java 6 use, `parseInt(n, 10)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I changed it to 00001, 00002, 00003 rtc. In my database schema I descirbed number as SMALLINT(5). Should it be INT instead?? I keep getting java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: You could try INT, take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). Just inspect the variables. Most likely the error lays elsewhere.

Comment: I keep getting a com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.mysqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception duplicate entry for '' key 'primary error!! I messed up on creating a composite key. I give up now